# AWS S3 Transfer Manager hangs at 32kb

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've got a weird issue using the AWS S3TransferManager in iOS. My putObjectRequests seem to hang at 32kb when I use short-term credentials to send them. Here's how my app is setup:

I've got a model than can upload images to S3. It uses the following method to do so:

```
- (void)putFileToS3:(NSData *)file withFilename:(NSString *)filename
{
  S3PutObjectRequest *por = [[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:filename inBucket:@"my-bucket"];
  por.data = file;
  por.cannedACL = [S3CannedACL publicRead];
  [self.tm upload:por];
}
```

self.tm is an s3TransferManager property of this object. The relevant parts of this are set up during the object init like so:

```
self.s3 = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:accessKey withSecretKey:secretKey];
self.tm = [S3TransferManager new];
self.tm.s3 = self.s3;
self.tm.delegate = self;
```

s3 and tm are strong properties:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AmazonS3Client *s3;
@property (strong, nonatomic) S3TransferManager *tm;
```

When I was first testing this I just pasted the accessKeyId and secretAccessKey into the object. However, this is not the recommended approach, so I setup STS on my server and now am generating short-term credentials on the server which are used in the app.

My ruby server is generating the short-term credentials using the ruby SDK, like so:

```
sts = AWS::STS.new
policy = AWS::STS::Policy.new
policy.allow :actions => ["s3:*"], :resources => "arn:aws:s3:::my-app-bucket/#{self.id}/*"
session = sts.new_federated_session "plc_user_#{id}",:policy => policy
```

The code still works - EXCEPT - now that I'm using short-term credentials all transfers stop at 32768 bytes transfered. Files smaller than that go ok, files larger just hang there forever.

Has anyone run into a similar problem? Is the issue here the credentials, the upload code, or something else?

Comment: In my demo app I set initWithAccessKey:withSecretKey: directly and face the exact same problem (eventually timing out after 32768 bytes).

Comment: I've run into several issues with the multipart uploads that the transfer manager is using. Could your credentials be timing out before a new part can be uploaded?